# All VBA Errors being supressed by setting AllowSpecialKeys to False

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been creating an MS Access database with VBA code performing a lot of the necessary actions as the users are not very technically literate. Everything has been working well until today when I noticed a command I was expecting an error from didn't return one.

Code executes until it encounters an error and then just stops with no message. The error details can be access through a messagebox with err.description or similar but no break occurs in the code, just an exit.

I tried creating a button on a new form that divided by 0 to force an error and received no message. I then tried it in a blank database and received the expected error.

So I went back and undid the recent changes I'd made one by one until the error messages returned. Once I set `AllowSpecialKeys` back to true the error functionality returned. I looked on `MSDN` and it says the property disables "entering break mode within a Visual Basic module by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd>". It seems that rather than stopping the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> combination it just disables VBA's ability to enter break mode.

I have the AllowSpecialKeys set to false to prevent the users from bringing up the Access Object explorer with F11 or the code window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

So my question is I guess, can I either continue to use `AllowSpecialKeys = False` and still allow VBA to enter break mode, and if not is there a different way to disable the hotkeys so I can avoid `AllowSpecialKeys`?

Comment: I would highly recommend to add error handlers to your code. In this case you won't need to go to break mode in production mode. For debugging enable Special Keys

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735162/ms-access-multi-control-keypress-ctrla-handler