# MS Access Multi-control KeyPress CTRL+A Handler

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have an Access database with 10+ text controls. I'd like to have some code to handle the CTRL + A KeyPress event. Normally, when pressing CTRL + A in Access, this selects **all** records. My end goal is to have CTRL + A only select that control's text (like pressing CTRL + A in your browser's URL bar, it only selects THAT text) so that I can delete only that control's text. I checked [this article](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/form-controls-single-event-handler-for-multiple-controls-without-sacrifices), as I wanted something that could handle any text box (handling each textbox's KeyPress = 60+ lines of code). Is there any way I could have, say, a for-next loop?

```
Function HandleKeyPress(frm As Form, KeyAscii As Integer, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) 'should it be a function or a sub?
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If KeyAscii = 1 Then    'I think this is CTRL + A?
            e.Handled = True    'Stop this keypress from doing anything in access
            focused_text_box.SelStart = 0
            focused_text_box.SelLength = Len(focused_text_box.Text)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Along with this, how can I pass to this sub/function the text box's name?

Note: In case you haven't noticed yet, I'm still a noob with VBA/Access.

Comment: Did you put this code in a VBA module? Did you run Debug>Compile? It errors on the KeyPressEventArgs. This appears to be a VB.net class and Access VBA does not recognize it, unless there is a reference library I need to activate.

Comment: if all you want, is to select the control content so that you can delete it, then just delete without selecting `control.text = ""`

Comment: I knew that this would most likely result in an error, I just wasn't sure what an equivalent would be in VBA. Looking back, I should've just looked it up, my apologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your current approach will not work, since it contains multiple things that just don't work that way in VBA (as June7 noted), and since form keydown events take priority over textbox keydown events

You can use the following code instead (inspired by [this answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/74062/851686)):

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyA And Shift = acCtrlMask Then 'Catch Ctrl+A
        KeyCode = 0 'Suppress normal effect
        On Error GoTo ExitSub 'ActiveControl causes a runtime error if none is active
        If TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is TextBox Then
            With Me.ActiveControl
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = Len(.Text)
            End With
        End If
    End If
ExitSub:
End Sub
```

It's important to set the `Form.KeyPreview` property to True, either using VBA or just the property pane, to allow this function to take priority over the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you guys! I'm sorry June7 keeps having to deal with my crappy questions! lol sorry june