# To paste a macro from Stack Overflow into Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

My question seems to be very silly, but I haven't found solution myself.

Is there a way to simply paste a macro ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735162/ms-access-multi-control-keypress-ctrla-handler)) from Stack Overflow in Access? Or, alternatively, paste it from Access to Stack Overflow?

I know, it is very easy in Word and Excel. But I can't understand how to do it in Access.

Comment: The example is not a macro, it is VBA. Macros in Access are very different. Yes, VBA code posted in SO question can be copy/pasted into a code module. How do you find it different from Word and Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic questions certainly deserve asking, if they're not duplicates.

There are a couple of different cases:

1. Add VBA on a form event (this case)

   - Open up the form in design view
   - Identify the control you want to add the macro to (the part before the `_` is the control name, the part after the `_` is the event name, so the `KeyDown` event on the form control.
   - Identify the event you want to add code to on the event pane
   - Press the builder `...` thing
   - Choose *Code Builder* and press OK.
   - You will see some event code has already been added. Replace that with the copy-pasted code.

[image]

2. Add VBA  (function or sub) outside of a form (triggered elsewhere, such as a user-defined function for use in queries)

   - Open up the VBA editor by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
   - Choose *Insert* -> *Module* in the top bar
   - Paste the code
3. Paste a normal, non-VBA macro using AXL

   - Create a macro on the create tab on the ribbon
   - Select the body of the macro by clicking the blank space inside it (not the area where you can create new controls)
   - Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd> to paste
4. Paste an Access data macro using AXL

   - Open the table you want to add the data macro to in design view.
   - In the ribbon, click *Create data macros*, choose and click the right event. You can identify the event by looking at the event property of the datamacro tag, for example `<DataMacro Event="AfterInsert">` = On After Insert
   - Select the body of the macro by clicking the blank space inside it (not the area where you can create new controls)
   - Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd> to paste

Note that questions about non-VBA macros rarely contain the AXL necessary to paste it. Pasting AXL is somewhat contra-intuitive, as you don't paste it in a textbox and the result isn't text.

Comment: I love your handwriting numbers style! xD

Comment: It complements the [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/369403) with extra freehand :)