# How to edit and copy non-VBA-macros?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Well, I know, there is a difference between VBA-macros and non-VBA-macros in Access.

Creating and editing of VBA-macros is not very different from Word/Excel: you have a text field, where you can write your code:

[image]

But what about editing of non-VBA-macros? For me, it looks like "programming using a mouse-clicking" (for me, as for the new guy in Access, it looks very weird):

[image]

Questions:

- Is it a common and correct way to edit non-VBA-macros in Access "using a mouse"? Or, probably, there is another way, like shown on the 1st image?
- If I have an [embedded (as opposed to standalone)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-macro-c1ae8cc4-4464-4dc6-9bac-9e1651230eb3) non-VBA-macro, how I can copy it from one database to another (or, to Stack Overflow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-VBA macros should probably not be manually edited.

You can copy the AXL by opening the macro, using Ctrl + A, Ctrl + C, and then pasting it to a text file. This is mainly useful for sharing a macro, because others can paste it, as outlined here: [To paste a macro from Stack Overflow into Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487686/7296893).

You can copy and paste the AXL of normal, embedded and data macros. Note that data macros use a different set of functions than normal macros, and the availability differs per event. Normal and embedded macros are compatible.

You can, of course, edit the AXL. But as far as I know, there's no way to edit it from Access, and there's no validation outside of XML validation.

Comment: Thanks, Erik :) Here is what was copied after Ctrl-A Ctrl-C: https://i.imgur.com/h6HvH5G.png. Is it what we tried to achieve? Then, you say: "Non-VBA macros should probably not be manually edited." - as I understand, you discourage me about editing it inside external text editor (Notepad, Vim, etc), but there is no harm to edit it with "mouse-clicking" in Access?

Comment: I mainly discourage it because it&#39;s a very specific language, and outside Access, you can invalidate a macro easily, with no tools to debug/troubleshoot it. But if you really wish, you're free to try, of course. In Access editing is very constrained, so invalidating it is harder.

Comment: I understand :) So, normally it should be edited inside Access, with mouse-clicks?

Comment: Yes, that's the normal way. I recommend using VBA wherever possible, though, since it's more versatile

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can convert an Access Macro into its equivalent Visual Basic code using the `Convert Macros to Visual Basic` option present on the `Tools` panel of the `Macro Tools` `Design` contextual ribbon tab:

[image: Convert VBA]

This will result in the creation of a VBA Module similar to what may be created when you record a Macro in MS Excel or MS Word.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a macro from one database to another in the same was as with any other object in Access.

External Data -> New Data Source -> From Database -> Access -> Import