# Microsoft access editing marcro

Tags: ms-access, edit

I would like to edit one macro in a project but do not really know how to do it.
I wish to see the source code.. the macro is not visible if I press alt-f11.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I got the answer, just had to convert macro to vb..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access macros are **NOT** VBA subs/functions, and thus can't be viewed in the VBA editor.

You're currently looking at all the code the macro contains, which is literally nothing.

Macros are made out of draggable blocks. The underlying code is AXL. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49585786/7296893) for how to edit and copy them.

Alternatively, you can click the *Convert Macros to Visual Basic* button to convert them to VBA code, but that's not very sensible if it doesn't contain anything.

Comment: just did it mate, anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, just had to convert macro to vba..