# MS Access 2016: CTRL+A saves the form?

Tags: ms-access

I have a strange problem that I don't know how to track down. 
I have a form that closes itself using an `_AfterUpdate` event. I found, by accident, that when I am inside a TextBox control and I attempt to select all text using `CTRL+A` that the form updates. This causes the _AfterUpdate to run and the form closes. The effect is that pressing `CTRL+A` is now "save and quit" instead of "select all text", as expected.

I've dug through all of my events and none of them are trapping keys like CTRL or A. I only have one button called "Submit" and it is the default button. I haven't found any other key combo that causes this behavior.

Does anyone know of any reason that pressing CTRL+A while in a TextBox would update the form?

**BONUS POINTS**: Does anyone know how I can trace what is happening? How do I break on the action to see what is capturing this key comobo? How do I even troubleshoot this?

**CURRENT WORKAROUND:**
I am now using a Submit button pressed flag and a `_BeforeUpdate` event to determine if the Sumbit button was pressed so I can cancel the update if the button was not pressed. The side-effect of this workaround is that now pressing `CTRL+A` does nothing. It does not select all but at least it doesn't submit the form either. Now I'm double confused as to where the `CTRL+A` is going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS-Access textboxes don't react to Ctrl+A. To select all text in a textbox, click its associated label, or TAB into it.

Ctrl+A always selects all records (in a continuous form or datasheet) or the current record (in single form). This automatically saves the current record, invoking `AfterUpdate`.

---

Edit: some thoughts on simulating Ctrl+A in textboxes:

Set `Form.KeyPreview` = True

Trap Ctrl+A in `Form_KeyDown`

Use `Screen.ActiveControl` to determine the active control

If it's a textbox, use `SelStart` and `SelLength` to select its content.

Comment: Holy testicle Tuesday! I have been chasing my tail over a complete misunderstanding of the interface. How shameful. This is unfortunate. Maybe the question should be "How can I use CTRL+A to select all in a textbox".

Comment: :D I guess you can trap it with a `KeyDown` event, and then use `SelStart` and `SelLength`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that if I must but it would be a pain to do that to each control... Maybe I could script the event creation to every textbox control....

Comment: It may be possible on form level (and using public functions so you can re-use them), see edit.

Comment: Oh, I just re-invented https://stackoverflow.com/a/47737371/3820271 ...