# How to use Ctrl+A in a MS-Access textbox in order to select all the text - standard module option

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox, keydown, ctrl

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735162/ms-access-multi-control-keypress-ctrla-handler) that will allow me to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> combo in an Access textbox in order to select all of the text inside it.

This solution needs:

1. Set the`Form.KeyPreview` property to `True`
2. Add the following code to the `Form.Keydown`:

```vb
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyA And Shift = acCtrlMask Then 'Catch Ctrl+A
        KeyCode = 0 'Suppress normal effect
        On Error GoTo ExitSub 'ActiveControl causes a runtime error if none is active
        If TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is TextBox Then
            With Me.ActiveControl
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = Len(.Text)
            End With
        End If
    End If
ExitSub:
End Sub
```

I tried to put this code in a module like this:

```vb
Public Sub CtrlA(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyA And Shift = acCtrlMask Then 'Catch Ctrl+A
        KeyCode = 0 'Suppress normal effect
        On Error GoTo ExitSub 'ActiveControl causes a runtime error if none is active
        If TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is TextBox Then
            With Me.ActiveControl
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = Len(.Text)
            End With
        End If
    End If
ExitSub:
End Sub
```

In order to call it wherever I want like this:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Call CtrlA(KeyCode, Shift)
End Sub
```

But the `Me` keyword isn't allowed in a standard module.

How can I achive this goal?

Comment: If you are going to do it that way, then include the textbox control as an argument to the function in the module too, then reference that variable instead of the way you are doing it now.

Comment: can you show me how?!

Comment: `Public Sub CtrlA(txt As TextBox, KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)`

Comment: i tried with your textbox argument but now it tells me "ByRef argument type mismatch" regard Keycode on the `Call CtrlA(KeyCode, Shift)` line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your code sample this is what you want:

You have to forward the control (here it is named `text0`) to your procedure.

The argument `KeyCode` must be defined `ByRef` to be able to return the value `0` to the calling procedure.

> Call it like this from in a form:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Call CtrlA(Text0, KeyCode, Shift)
End Sub
```

> In a module:

```
Public Sub CtrlA(ByVal contextControl As Control, ByRef KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyA And Shift = acCtrlMask Then 'Catch Ctrl+A
        KeyCode = 0 'Suppress normal effect
        On Error GoTo ExitSub 'ActiveControl causes a runtime error if none is active
        If TypeOf contextControl Is TextBox Then
            With contextControl
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = Len(.Text)
            End With
        End If
    End If

ExitSub:
End Sub
```

---

Following Andres suggestion (thx to him) to pass the form itself, you can do it like this:

> Call it like this from in a form:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Call CtrlA(Me, KeyCode, Shift)
End Sub
```

> In a module:

```
Public Sub CtrlA(ByVal contextForm As Form, ByRef KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyA And Shift = acCtrlMask Then 'Catch Ctrl+A
        KeyCode = 0 'Suppress normal effect
        On Error GoTo ExitSub 'ActiveControl causes a runtime error if none is active
        If TypeOf contextForm.ActiveControl Is TextBox Then
            With contextForm.ActiveControl
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = Len(.Text)
            End With
        End If
    End If

ExitSub:
End Sub
```

Comment: To make this work with multiple controls, it would be better to pass the form (`Me`) as parameter, and use `F.ActiveControl` in the module. Hmm, or use `Screen.ActiveControl`.